# Why my custom class is not applied to body when adding it through jQuery with gmap event click listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, events, onclick

I want to open a slide menu when clicking a gmap marker, but I can't. Here is how I proceeded to achieve that:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {  
    $('body').toggleClass("side-panel-open");
    if( $('body').hasClass('device-touch') ) {
       $('body').toggleClass("ohidden");
    }
    return false;
});
```

The same thing is working well with a normal button, when I manage that this way:

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass("side-panel-open");
    if( $('body').hasClass('device-touch') ) {
        $('body').toggleClass("ohidden");
    }
    return false;
});
```

As you can see there:

http://www.themes.krown.ch/canvas4/HTML/index-fullscreen-image_test.html

The "TEST" button on the footer, is working perfectly. Unfortunately, when clicking the gmap marker, nothing happens. I can see on Firebug that something happens on body, but the class "side-panel-open" doesn't stay.

I also tried to just add a class to the body, this way:

```
$('body').addClass('side-panel-open');
```

Nothing happens as with the first code. This is so strange because if I try to add another class, for exemple "class_name". This class will be applied as expected to the body:

```
$('body').addClass('class_name');
```

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple

Answer (score 0):

For the button, you can use the jQuery [`click event`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) or if you're using a different javascript framework, they will likely have a click event as well. For jQuery, you would do the following:

```
$('#boundaries-states').click(function () {
//Do something
});
```

It looks like the [`addListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.23/reference#MapsEventListener) method takes the google Map object, not the HTML element for the map. Take a look at the first example here. Programs interested in certain events will register JavaScript event listeners for those events and execute code when those events are received by calling `addListener()` to register event handlers on the object.

So if you're not already, you'll need to hold onto the reference to your map that is returned when you instantiate the map:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('boundaries-states'),
mapOptions);
Once you have your map reference, you can add a listener using the map object, rather than the HTML element.

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
alert('clicked');
});
```